# Converting float to int32 when parsing csv using tiny csv helper

Tags: c#, csv

I wonder is it possible to convert float to int32 automatically when parsing csv using tiny csv helper?
Datetime is easily converted using the code below:

`MapProperty(0, x => x.Date, new DateTimeConverter("yyyyMMdd"));`

but other columns in csv are in format 123456.00 and it raises error when I map to an int property.
Can anyone give an example on how to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: What is *"tiny csv helper"* ? where did you get it, what is the github link, where is the documentation?

Comment: Why don't you map them to double?

Comment: @TheGeneral https://github.com/TinyCsvParser/TinyCsvParser The exact name is tiny csv parser.

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane These are prices in int format and int is enough for my work.

Comment: I see but what I see is value with .00 is that a double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, one solution to this is to define your own ITypeConverter as follows :

```
using TinyCsvParser.TypeConverter;
using System;

public class CustomIntConverter : ITypeConverter<int>{ 

    public bool TryConvert(string value, out int result)
    {
       try { 
            float floatValue = float.Parse(value); 
            int intValue = (int)floatValue; 
            result = intValue;
            return true; 
        } catch {
            result = default(int);
            return false;
        }

    }

    public Type TargetType { get => typeof(int); } 


}
```

and use it like this :

```
MapProperty(0, x => x.YourIntField, new CustomIntConverter());
```